# NAT not working in cisco packet tracer

Tags: cisco, nat, packet-tracer

Cisco Router Version: 16.7(3r)
Cisco Packet Tracer:8.0 x64

```
Router(config)#interface dialer 1
Router(config-if)#ip nat?
% Unrecognized command
Router(config-if)#ip nat ?
% Unrecognized command
Router(config)#interface g0/0/0
Router(config-if)#ip nat
Router(config-if)#ip nat ?
  inside   Inside interface for address translation
  outside  Outside interface for address translation
Router(config-if)#ip nat
```

NAT's not working in cisco packet tracer.I created dialer interface.
and I can't define nat outside command to this interface. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t. Packet Tracer is just a learning tool with very basic functionalities, and not everything a real device can do was built into Packet Tracer. You can try using GNS3 or Cisco VIRL instead, but your best bet is to just get your hands on a real device (maybe from eBay or Amazon) to use as a lab.